# sed not deleting the lines even with the 'd' flag

Tags: awk, sed, zsh

I am trying to delete all the dupes from a csv file:

```zsh
awk -F ',' '{print $2}' file.csv | sort | uniq -d | xargs -I{} zsh -c "ggrep -n {} file.csv | tail +2 | awk -F':' '{print \$1}' | xargs -I% gsed '%d' file.csv"
```

I am using a d flag to delete the lines, but it is just printing all the lines to the STDOUT. What may be causing this?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code attempt, please do share sample of input and expected output to make it more clear in your question, that will make your question more clear, thank you.

Comment: My two cents: the above code is unreadable and hard to debug. Just write a simple script using a real CSV parser library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Zsh, if you want to eliminate duplicate lines in a file, you can just do this:

```
print -l ${(fu)"$( < file.csv )"} > file.csv
```

- `< ...` outputs the contents of the file.
- `$( ... )` captures the output into a string.
- `"$( ... )` ensures line breaks are preserved.
- `${(f)...}` splits the string on line breaks and converts it into an array.
- `${(u)...}` eliminates duplicate entries from the array.
- `print -l` prints each entry from the array on a separate line.
- `> file.csv` redirects the output back into the file.

More info in the Zsh manual:

- [Parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion)
- [Command substitution](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution)
- [`print` builtin](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print)